# How to modify a Linux kernel header file without compiling like livepatch?

Tags: linux-kernel, false-sharing, hotpatching

I want to change struct members layout in a header file to prevent false sharing.But I have to recompile the entire kernel and install the new kernel after that.

Is there any methods to modify Linux kernel header file without recompiling the entire kernel?
Livepatch only support modifing some functions in c file, but not header file.

I tried to make some code modifications in the .c file, but doing so can introduce unpredictable risks.

Comment: Header files are only used by the compiler.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thank you for answer. Is there anything similar method to kernel hotpatching if I want to avoid the false sharing problem by reayouting a struct in a header file?

Comment: You would need to compile the kernel anyway to determine the binary diffs for a hot patch.